# PIC18LF24K40 I2C read and write using Polling method

Tags: pic, c, i2c, microchip, xc8

I'm trying to implement read and write routines using Polling method for a PIC18LF24K40, write seems to work, but not read. I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.

EDIT: Reading a byte stored in a register on a slave chip:

```
   void read_LDC_reg(U8 *dest_addr)
   {
      U8 temp=0;   

      if( ( check_for_bus_free_iic() == 1) )   
      send_start();

      PIR3bits.SSP1IF=0;
      I2C_wait();  

      send_address(U8_LDC_I2C_ADDRESS,READ_BIT);

      send_start();
      SSP1CON2bits.RCEN1=1;

      while(SSP1STATbits.BF==0);
      temp=read_from_slave();

      PIR3bits.SSPIF = 0;

      dest_addr =  &temp;

      send_stop();

}
```

`send_start()` looks like this:

```
void send_start()
{
    while(SSP1STATbits.RW);          // wait for write to complete
    SSP1CON2bits.SEN=1;              //set start enable bit

    if(PIR3bits.BCLIF==1)
        PIR3bits.BCLIF =0;  //Clear collision bit in PIR register

    while(SSP1CON2bits.SEN);         //waits to get cleared by hardware 
}
```

`I2C_wait` looks like this:

```
void I2C_wait(void)
{
    while( (SSP1STAT & 0x04) | (SSP1CON2 & 0x1F) );

    PIR3bits.BCL1IF=0;

}
```

`send_address()` looks like this:

```
void send_address(unsigned char addr,unsigned char ReadWrite_bit)
{
    unsigned char temp=0;
    temp = ( (addr <<1u ) | (ReadWrite_bit & (unsigned char)0x01) ); 
    write_to_bus(temp);


}
```

`write_to_bus()` looks like this:

```
void write_to_bus(unsigned char data)
{

    send_start();
    I2C_wait();

    send_byte(data);
    I2C_wait(); 

    send_stop();        
}
```

`read_from_slave()` looks like this:

```
unsigned char read_from_slave(void)
{  
    unsigned char rcvd_byte=0;   

    rcvd_byte = SSP1BUF;     
    return rcvd_byte;    
}
```

I am getting unexpected values from the slave register, i do not know why i believe i have initialised correctly, i can see the SCL and SDA waveforms on Oscilloscope.

**EDIT:** Hardware is fine, I2C works perfectly when i use the I2C Driver code generated from MCC(MPLAB Code Generator), i want to reduce the overhead caused by MCC in my project, thats the reason im going for I2C using Polling option.

Comment: How do you know the writes are working if you can't read?  Do you have access to registers on the other device?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may have very little to do with I2C and much more to do with your use of the stack and pointers.

I see some issues with the following code.

> ```
>    void read_LDC_reg(U8 *dest_addr)
>    {
>       U8 temp=0;
>       ...
>       temp=read_from_slave();
>       ...
>       dest_addr =  &temp;
>       ...
>   }
> ```

It looks like you are attempting to store a byte into temp and then return the address of temp from the function.  There are two problems with this.

- Temp is stored on the stack.  So when you return it no longer exists.  The compiler can re-use that stack space for other stuff, which would over-write your value.
- You are not actually returning the address of temp properly.  dest_addr is a pointer to an 8 bit integer.  It lives on the stack.  When you return from the function it no longer exists.

What you should be doing is...

- Allocating temp somewhere outside of the read_LDC_reg function.
- Passing the address of temp into the function.
- Dereferencing the pointer address to store the value into temp.

The code is shown below.

```
void main(){
    U8 temp=0;
    read_LDC_reg(&temp);
    //At this point temp contains the byte read from I2C
}

void read_LDC_reg(U8 *temp){
      ...
      *temp=read_from_slave();
      ...
      send_stop();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load test values in a dummy MCU and try simulating with the Proteus design suite, but i agree with Buhra with checking the flag for successful reception from the slave, and if possible check necessary flags that indicate a free buffer and transmission-ready state.

Answer (score -1):

```
unsigned char read_from_slave(void)
{  
    unsigned char rcvd_byte=0;   
   <----------- Check Flag ------------>
    rcvd_byte = SSP1BUF;     
    return rcvd_byte;    
}
```

In this function you are not check any flag for successfull reception from slave,Check datasheet again

Comment: I have not enabled ACKEN bit so I'm not sure if i need to check if ACKDT bit is set on Receive. Probably i have to set ACKEN

Comment: what do you mean by 
**I have not enabled ACKEN bit .** Check previous reception is complete or not using flag,there is no matter of ACK.

Comment: I modified the read from register routine, i check if the buffer is now full, but i receive 0xFF for some reason, always.

Comment: ReCheck your connections, I2C Master SDA -> Slave SDA and SCK -> SCK with pull ups 1K'oms -> 4.7k'oms and what freq you are using for I2C communication can you provied whole code.

Comment: Pullups are around 2.2K, Clock frequency is set to 100KHz. Hardware is fine, I2C works perfectly when i use the I2C Driver code generated from MCC(MPLAB Code Generator), i want to reduce the overhead in my project, thats the reason im going for I2C using Polling option.